# opencv cvfitline is giving doubtful results

Tags: opencv, line, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am using OpenCV's function cvFitLine and it is giving me results that I find very doubtful. Basically, you can see that I am inputting coordinates of points pretty much along a line with 2 outliers. I am using the Huber distance measure to ignore the outliers. The resulting fitted line however is a diagonal line that seems to be taking the outliers very much into account. Am i doing something wrong? is anybody getting similar results?

(edit) The result should obviously be a straight line analogous to {vx,vy,x0y0} = {0,1,531,0} but openCV gives me {0.85, -0.53, 453,144} which is not remotely vertical.

```
CvPoint * points=(CvPoint*)malloc( 13 * sizeof(points[0]));

points[0].x = 531;points[0].y = 0;
points[1].x = 531;points[1].y = 20;
points[2].x = 530;points[2].y = 40;
points[3].x = 531;points[3].y = 60;
points[4].x = 530;points[4].y = 80;
points[5].x = 531;points[5].y = 100;
points[6].x = 531;points[6].y = 120;
points[7].x = 531;points[7].y = 140;
points[8].x = 531;points[8].y = 160;
points[9].x = 531;points[9].y = 180;
points[10].x = 531;points[10].y = 200;
points[11].x = 273;points[11].y = 260;
points[12].x = 141;points[12].y = 280;
float testPar[4];// to store the results
CvMat point_mat = cvMat( 1, 13, CV_32SC2, points );
cvFitLine(&point_mat,CV_DIST_HUBER ,0,0.01,0.01,testPar);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not input the coordinates correctly, if you notice there are two x coordinates that are of value 530 whereas they should be 531. These two points are malfunctioning (i.e. the ones with the value 530). The rest is OK.

Comment: Shouldnt the line still be in the neighborhood of 530-531 rather than what i'm getting, which seems to be weighting much heavier on the 2 outliers [11] and [12]?